# DocBook: Specifying code or markup

Tags: xml, pdf, markup, docbook

You can specify equations using `<equation>` and also several others, but what tag must be used to specify code? More specifically, PHP, HTML, CSS and Javascript? Is there a plugin that you can use with OxygenXML to add these features automatically? I need to output as PDF.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm working on a project which uses docbook, and has examples in PHP.

The examples in PHP are using [`programlisting`](http://www.docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/programlisting.html) tag, like this :

```
<programlisting language="php"><![CDATA[<?php

// Here goes the PHP code

]]></programlisting>
```

Note the language attribute.

It is used later by another tool to add syntax-coloration, when generating the ouput (for HTML output, at least)

For examples that are not specific to one programming language, like configuration files, we are using the [`screen`](http://www.docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/screen.html) tag ; for instance, for a part of an Apache-related config file, an example would be :

```
<screen><![CDATA[# Setup Listening Port
NameVirtualHost *:80

# Ensure "localhost" is preserved unchanged pointed
# to the default document root for our system.
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>]]></screen>
```

Quoting their documentations :

> A programlisting is a verbatim
>   environment for program source or
>   source fragment listings. The
>   programlistings are often placed in
>   examples or figures so that they can
>   be cross-referenced from the text.

And :

> A screen is a verbatim environment for
>   displaying text that the user might
>   see on a computer terminal. It is
>   often used to display the results of a
>   command.
>
> Having less specific semantic
>   overtones, screen is often used
>   wherever a verbatim presentation is
>   desired, but the semantic of
>   programlisting is inappropriate.

So, these two seem quite appropriate.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! One question though... if I include something like <html> which is a tag, it doesn't work. Maybe know how to get around that?

Comment: I'm not the one who worked on the build process, so I don't really know ; still, using CDATA should help, in the docbook file. Then, when generating the ouput (HTML output, for instance), you will, probably, need to escape some stuff, or use <pre> tags (it's what we are doing, apparently)...